# append element to last in its own div

Tags: jquery, html

I have ten divs with class `pcre` in a single div whose id is `huge`.How can I move div(having class=pcre) to last in div(id=huge) on `mouseclick` with jQuery

I have tried

```
<div id="huge">
   <div class="pcre">a</div>
    <div class="pcre">b</div>
    <div class="pcre">c</div>
    <div class="pcre">d</div>
    <div class="pcre">e</div>
    <div class="pcre">f</div>
    <div class="pcre">g</div>
    <div class="pcre">h</div>
    <div class="pcre">i</div>
    <div class="pcre">j</div>
    </div>
<script>
  $(".pcre").click(function() {
       $(this).appendTo("#huge");$(this).remove(); 
  });
</script>
```

**But its not working.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma before your function(), and you also don't need the .remove();

```
<div id="huge">
   <div class="pcre">a</div>
    <div class="pcre">b</div>
    <div class="pcre">c</div>
    <div class="pcre">d</div>
    <div class="pcre">e</div>
    <div class="pcre">f</div>
    <div class="pcre">g</div>
    <div class="pcre">h</div>
    <div class="pcre">i</div>
    <div class="pcre">j</div>
    </div>
<script>
$(".pcre").click(function(){
$(this).appendTo("#huge"); 
 });</script>​
```

Comment: It gets moved, there's no need to delete it.

Comment: @AnkitGautam - Unless your purpose has been misstated, I believe Jonathan's answer is the on you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/TPHy8/4/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/TPHy8/6/

You have extra `,` comma in your code. remove it and bingo!! B-) Anyhoo and '.remove` can be removed.

Hope this helps bruv! please let me know if I am missing anything else!

**code**

**updated**

```
$(".pcre").click(function(){
$(this).appendTo("#huge");
   // $(this).remove(); 
 });​

$(".pcre").click(function(){
$(this).appendTo("#huge");
    $(this).remove(); 
 });​
```

Comment: Good work, but I don't think you'd need to remove the element after appending it.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yeah bruv indeed :) I reused whats given above, but thank-you B-), have a nice one! Cheerios!

Comment: Hiya @AnkitGautam updated the code, hope this helps, cheers <I used the code from your example> :) Thanks for message, cheerios mate!

Comment: lol **brother** down voter care to comment :) please! have a nice one, cheerios!

Comment: Just an observation, @Jonathan Payne posted a code without the `.remove();` before you, but you posted a fiddle which makes it quite clear that `.remove()` was unneeded before him, so I'm keeping my up vote. Cheers :)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté saweet Thanks B-)) legend, cheerios!